# Single Sign On between Azure website and website hosted in Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have 2 websites. Website #1 hosted in Azure Virtual Machine and website #2 is an Azure website(i.e Website hosted in Azure App service - Web Apps).

If user logs into website 1 and access website 2, user should be automatically logged into site 2 and vice-verse.

How to implement this Single Sign On between these sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use Azure Active Directory:

Here's a very good resourse from asp.net website:

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/single-sign-on

More resources:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/home/